# How to control output precision when running WRF?

Tags: atmosphere-modelling, numerical-modelling, wrf

I am very new in this area and wondering if anyone can answer my following questions:

I am running WRF (4.0.3, ideal) to study rounding and truncation. I use the NCL (6.5.0) print command to access variable values in the WRF output file.

1. I have noticed that some variables have greater precision than others. Is there a way to change the level of precision for individual variables?
2. I have been using em_b_wave and ideal.exe to initialize the WRF model. The values and variables in the output file are the same no matter how many MPI tasks I use. Why?
3. Is WRF output exactly the same when using a single MPI task vs. using more than one MPI task? I assume there might be slight differences in rounding and truncation when using different number of processors.
4. And at the end, I am not sure if the way that I am reading the values and variables from the output files which are binary are correct or not. I am using some NCL scripts now, but have no idea if that is the right way to read the binary output files ...

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you,
Sara

Comment: These are four questions in one post.